# CodeIgniter php framework: js and css files inside "application" folder. How to do?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I just installed the php framework CodeIgniter 3 and it seems that JS,CSS and images should be placed OUTSIDE `Application` folder. If not, link to those files inside views does not run.

For many reasons I would like to have these kind of files inside `application/views` folder. I think that I should correctly set .htaccess file, but I would also like to "***lower my defenses less possible***", so give only strict necessary privileges.

How to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: Don't do it. It's a bad idea.

Comment: Ok, could be a bad idea from your point of view, but sometimes there are needs that are not ideal, but necessary for many reasons. I only would like to know how to set up my system in a specific case like this.

Comment: There shouldn't ever be a **need** to do this. Images, JavaScript, and CSS files are not views and should not be in the views folder for that reason. Your application folder shouldn't ever be accessible by the web server for critical security reasons.

Comment: Let's consider to download and integrate a complex 3rd party plugin which include .php, .js, .css files. Generally all files are inside a folder with the plugin name. With standard CodeIgniter folder tree, I need to split each file in different folders instead of mantain all grouped, right? .php (=views) files in application/view, .css in assets/css, .js in assets/js. Am I correct? It seems very uncomfortable

Comment: You'd likely want to turn it into a package for something like http://getsparks.org/. You can also use stuff like Grunt/Gulp to handle moving assets into the right locations on deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|assets|js|images|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /your_ci_folder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain me what does it mean? I would like to better understand in order to lower defenses as low as possible. thanks

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention the .htaccess, load your assets from .htaccess file and the above should be in your .htaccess file.